# Android Studio cannot detected Android Support Repository

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with android Studio , I want to make an application that use google MAP,
I have two errors

[image]

[image]

When I checked the SDK manager I found Google Repository and support repository already downloaded. I tried to reinstall them the problem still in the android studio.
SDK manager :
[image]

Comment: Yeah it's a duplicate of my problem. but the answer is not really acceptable because I can't compile

Comment: Regardless of whether or not "a fix is coming" is an acceptable answer to you, that is the correct answer. Your options until Android Studio 0.5.9 is released are to either downgrade to a previous version of AS that worked or use another IDE for the time being.